# Singleton class and instance variables

Tags: ruby, eval, irb

Why does the `instance_variables` method not show `@var_one` against the variable `a`?

```
a = Object.new

def a.my_eval; yield end

a.my_eval { @var_one = 1 }
a.instance_variables
# => []
instance_variables
# => [@var_one]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `instance_eval`:

```
a.instance_eval { @var_one = 1 }
=> 1
a.instance_variables
=> [:@var_one]
```

When you use ordinary `eval`, you define your instance variable in context of current `self`, if you do it in irb, it is the `main` object:

```
a.eval { self }
=> main
```

So, you can modify your `a.eval` method by executing a block in a context of an instance:

```
def a.eval(&block)
  instance_eval &block  
end

a.eval { @a = 1 }
=> 1
a.instance_variables
=> [:@a]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to set an instance variable programmatically, you can use:

```
a.instance_variable_set(:@var_one, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between `eval` and `instance eval`:

`Kernel.eval` evaluates a string in the current context or the context of the given binding. It is the method used by IRB to process your input. It allows you to define new variables and methods for the current context.

`Object.instance_eval` evaluates a string (or the given block) within the context of a certain class instance and allows thus the direct access to class properties without `attr` or `attr_accessor`. It allows you to define new methods for a instance.

So :

```
a.instance_eval { @var_one = 1 }
a.instance_variables
# => [:@var_one]
```

Comment: @mhaseev defined his own `eval`, so is not using `Kernel.eval`. I think the answer is more directly to do with the block's binding and how `yield` or `Proc#call` interacts with that binding.